# How to start next View in new tab after passing model to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm sending data from View to Controller, and returning matching data. Instead being redirected, I would like to start it in a new tab instead.

This is my partial View:

```
@model X.Models.ModelVm

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })               
            </div>
        </div>

        .....

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Get data" class="btn btn-default"/>                   
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Controller for this View above:

```
 public ActionResult GetInformation(ModelVm inData) {

       .....

            return View("ShowData", newModel);          
    }
```

Then `ShowData` method have it's own View that I want to start in new tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm(null,null,FormMethod.Post, new { target = "_blank" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">

            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })               
                </div>
            </div>

            .....

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Get data" class="btn btn-default"/>                   
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```